# How do you programmatically remove a comment in handsontable?

Tags: javascript, handsontable

I'm using handsontable and need to remove a comment programmatically, but haven't found a way to do it.  Looking through the code, it seems like you should be able to say:

```
var hot = new Handsontable(element, options);
hot.getPlugin('comment').removeCommentAtCell(row, column);
```

But hot.getPlugin() doesn't seem to work.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, I figure it out right after posting.  The plugin name is "comments" not "comment".  Comments within the handsontable source apparently need to be updated as they throw errors in certain situations and reference the plugin name of "comment" which is where I got the original idea.

Answer:

```
var hot = new Handsontable(element, options);
hot.getPlugin('comments').removeCommentAtCell(row, column);
```